# CSS/JS: Background image edge gradient to solid background

Tags: jquery, css, background

So imagine a website header, with this image as a `div` background:

[image]

Is it possible for me using CSS and JS/JQuery create a gradient at the image edges that will end up on transparency? Or a solid color?

My ideia was to apply the gradient to the background edges and then apply a solid color behind it resulting in this effect:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.container {
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrmAg.jpg");
  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.container::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(203, 130, 43, 1), rgba(203, 130, 42, 0));
  left: 0;
}

.container::after {
 background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(203, 130, 43, 1), rgba(203, 130, 42, 0));
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```